# How to restrict the payment via paypal account?

Tags: paypal

I am using AdaptivePayments API.

When I create a new transaction, which has not the sender specified,
after redirecting to PayPal, the login form has an option either to
login to your PayPal account, or to pay via Credit Card.

What I'm trying to do is to "remove" the credit card payment method
and allow only the users with PayPal account to complete the payment.

Is there any way how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at x.com forums - the key directive for the Pay request is 'fundingConstraint' - https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI#id098QF000M7Q.

Answer (score 0):

In your PayPal account profile under Website Payment Preferences you should see an option for PayPal Account Optional.  Make sure this is disabled and the option to pay without an account should go away.